# XERO send Invoice through email

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, xero-api

I have integrated XERO with my php(codeigniter) website, everything i have implemented is working just fine.
I want to send the invoice through an email i have created.

I am using XeroOAuth.

```php
//This line is working properly
$response = $this->XeroOAuth->request('GET', $this->XeroOAuth->url('Invoices/'.$invoiceId, 'core'), array(), "", 'pdf');


//but cant send email through xero api
$send_email = $this->XeroOAuth->request('POST', $this->XeroOAuth->url('Invoices/'.$invoiceId.'/Email', 'core'), array() );
```

As their documentation explain that, this line of code should trigger the xero send mail option, but its returning error 401

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using 
[XERO PHP](https://github.com/calcinai/xero-php)
and you can easily send invoice using,

```
$invoice->sendMail();
```